# Datapager и repeater в asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Выбрасывает ошибку Элемент управления "`Repeater1`" не реализует `IPageableItemContainer`.
Вот код:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  >
        <ItemTemplate>
    ...
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" 
  PagedControlID="Repeater1" PageSize="2" runat="server">
<Fields>
<asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
   ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
<asp:NumericPagerField />
<asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" 
        ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
</Fields>
</asp:DataPager>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку...

Answer (score 1):

Элемент `Repeater` не работает без доп усилий с `DataPager`, как например `ListView`, потому что не реализует интерфейс `IPageableItemContainer`, что собственно и написано в ошибке. Чтобы их таки подружить надо его реализовать, как например [здесь](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45163/Extend-Repeater-to-support-DataPager).